# D-Galactose effects on primates?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cell-biology, bio-mechanics

A lot of studies are made using D-Galactose as a accelerated aging model in rats and mice, but why not in non human primates? How much relevant is the galactose rat model for human health perpective? (in the sense that galactose can have similar bad effects in humans)

Comment: It helps to support your question with references - e.g. a review paper on use of D-Galactose as an aging model.

Comment: Have you any idea how expensive it is to do experiments in non-human primates, and how difficult it is to get ethical permission?  You generally need an extremely strong case relating to concrete high-priority human health benefits. Aging is not that.